# Manga where a girl with a spear performed a dance ritual to fight something that lives in a cave

Tags: story-identification, manga

From what I recalled, it’s mainly about a girl whose father was murdered due to him being framed I believe and the girl was forced to move somewhere else for her safety.

I don’t remember what happens after that but I do remember there was a focus on a cave where supposedly something lurks and was sort of like a trial for warriors. The girl wielded a spear or lance, and she entered the cave near the end of the series.  She did some sort of dance ritual with her spear against whatever thing was in the cave, or at least that’s what I recall.

The manga was, I believe, part of the historical genre with sort of a tribal theme to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it perhaps [Yami no Moribito](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/yami-no-moribito)

It fits exactly your description and is about spearfighters that perform a ceremony inside a cave to fight something.
The main character is a girl that uses a copy of her masters spear to navigate the labyrinth like cave.

Comment: Yes! That’s the one I’ve been trying to find! Thank you very much!